# Swagger Editor - Additional Properties Error

Tags: openapi, swagger-editor

I'm just starting to use Swagger Editor/OpenAPI 3 spec and so it's not going good so far.  I have installed and running Swagger Editor v. 3.15.2 on my local machine.

This is the yaml I have so far:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Test
paths:
  /object:
    post:
      summary: Create an object
      operationId: createObject
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Object"
    responses:
      '201':
        description: Created
components:
  schemas:
    Object:
      required:
        - name
        - description
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
```

And it's displaying this error:

```
Errors


Resolver error
e is undefined
Structural error at paths./object
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: responses
Jump to line 6
Structural error at paths./object.post
should have required property 'responses'
missingProperty: responses
Jump to line 7
```

I have ensured that I am using two spaces for all the indents.  When I copied the yaml from the editor and put it into Notepad++ it looked fine.  I also pasted it into another editor and noticed that it only used line feeds and not carriage returns. I updated it to use both and still get the same error.

I have looked at other questions with the same problem but none of the solutions worked for me.  So, not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small indentation problem.

Add one indentation level to

```
responses:
  '201':
    description: Created
```

So that you then have:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Test
paths:
  /object:
    post:
      summary: Create an object
      operationId: createObject
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Object"
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Created
components:
  schemas:
    Object:
      required:
        - name
        - description
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        description:
          type: string
```